# How to put duplicate numbers between brackets in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dice

I need some help with an excercise. It is about rolling a dice(thats put in an array) 40 times, and when you roll two the same numbers in a row, you gain 5 points. In the console it looks like this:

```
You roll the dice, the number is 5.
[6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5]
You won 5 points!!
```

Now i want the duplicate numbers between round brackets, so it will look like this:

```
[6, 4, (2, 2), 1, 5, (4, 4), 2, 1, 2, (3, 3), 1, 4, 3, (5, 5), (1, 1), (5, 5)]
```

this is my code so far:

```
var diceRolls = [];
    var getallen = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var totalDiceRolls = 0;
    var maxDiceRolls = 40;
    var totalPoints = 40;

function rollDice() {
 if (++totalDiceRolls > maxDiceRolls)
   {
       alert(maxDiceRolls + " dice rolls allowed at max!");
       return;
   }

   totalPoints--;

   var d1 = getallen[Math.floor(Math.random() * getallen.length)];
   console.log("You roll the dice, the number is "+d1+".");
      diceRolls.push(d1);
    console.log(diceRolls);



   if(diceRolls[diceRolls.length - 2] === d1) {
       totalPoints+=5;
       console.log("You won 5 points!!");
   } 
   console.log("You now have "+totalPoints+" points left.");
}
```

Comment: This is suspciously similar to a few other questions I saw posted earlier... did you create a new account? Please only have one account. ([this is the account from which the similar questions were posted](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3087682/youssef))

Comment: If there have been so many duplicate numbers, why is there only one "You won 5 points!!" logged?

Comment: It is also suspiciously similar to a question i answered earlier today. In fact it is so similar it even has the edits i made to the code to fulfill another requirement. The question has since been deleted though...

Comment: @Tibos Hmm, maybe this is a class assignment? I will look through recently deleted questions and try to find it

Comment: Why is this a duplicate, I mean in the other question, he was asking how to put numbers in an array, now he is asking how to format the array into a way to add bracket when logging the array, I just did a little function that was returning a string with all the brackets and can't post it =[